# Simple graphic display or display widget for Java

Tags: java, graphics

We're giving a demo in about a week of a program which calculates a couple of moving averages. It would be much cooler if we could display these averages graphically, like perfmon, instead of printing to the console. I'm looking for the fastest, easiest way to get this dynamic line-graph display onto a GUI ), the less programming required, the better. In an ideal world,  it would somehow receive printed output in a certain format and generate the dynamic graph based on that. Barring that, a very simple widget, free or otherwise, that can be implemented in a Java GUI. Keeping in mind I don't have much experience in Swing and always find it to be somewhat non-user friendly. Also, what are the possibilities of a browser-based solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is what you are looking for.

It does include a [MovingAverage class](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/MovingAverage.html), and you have [here a "Moving Average" Demo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartHighLowChartDemo2withamovingaverageoverlaidontop.htm)

[image]
<sub>(source: [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/JFreeChartHighLowChartDemo2.PNG))</sub>

Comment: I took the liberty to add a few links and illustration. Feel free to revert if you find those additions inappropriate.